# How to get Android Render Script Group work?

Tags: android, renderscript

I can get two separate intrinsics working, but not together in a ScriptGroup. I found document on how to use Script Group is extremely sparse.

Here is my code:

```
mRS = RenderScript.create(getActivity());

mInAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, mBitmapIn,
        Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
        Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT |
                Allocation.USAGE_GRAPHICS_TEXTURE |
                Allocation.USAGE_SHARED);

mOutAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, mBitmapOut,
        Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
        Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT |
                Allocation.USAGE_SHARED);

ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix gray = ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix.create(mRS, Element.U8_4(mRS));
gray.setGreyscale();

ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(mRS, Element.U8_4(mRS));
blur.setRadius(20.f);
blur.setInput(mInAllocation);

//gray.forEach(mInAllocation, mOutAllocation);
blur.forEach(mOutAllocation);

mOutAllocation.copyTo(mBitmapOut);
```

Both gray and blur work. And then I tried putting them together, the result is blank. Code:

```
// gray.forEach(mInAllocation, mOutAllocation);
// blur.forEach(mOutAllocation);
// mOutAllocation.copyTo(mBitmapOut);

ScriptGroup.Builder builder = new ScriptGroup.Builder(mRS);
builder.addKernel(gray.getKernelID());
builder.addKernel(blur.getKernelID());
builder.addConnection(mInAllocation.getType(), gray.getKernelID(), blur.getKernelID());

ScriptGroup group = builder.create();
group.setInput(gray.getKernelID(), mInAllocation);
group.setOutput(blur.getKernelID(), mOutAllocation);
group.execute();

mOutAllocation.copyTo(mBitmapOut);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue you are seeing and cross checked with notes from my earlier experiments with intrinsics. I think there are a few bugs in renderscript intrinsics code.

-1-
If you want to get a scripgroup working with intrinsics, the below sequence works.

```
mBlur.setInput(mInAllocation);
sBuilder = new ScriptGroup.Builder(mRS);
sBuilder.addKernel(mBlur.getKernelID());
sBuilder.addKernel(mColor.getKernelID());
sBuilder.addConnection(connect, mBlur.getKernelID(), mColor.getKernelID());

sGroup = sBuilder.create();
//  sGroup.setInput(mBlur.getKernelID(), mInAllocation); //See point 2
sGroup.setOutput(mColor.getKernelID(), mOutAllocation);
sGroup.execute();

mOutAllocation.copyTo(outBitmap);
mRS.finish();
```

-2-
Note the way how the input allocation is passed. The input allocation is passed to mBlur.setInput() and not to sGroup.setInput(). If sGroup.setInput() is used, then the group correctly does not find the input and it results in the following error and ofcourse, I dont see the transformed image on the screen as well.

```
E/RenderScript(12023): rsAssert failed: !"ScriptGroup:setInput kid not found", in frameworks/rs/rsScriptGroup.cpp at 267
```

In this specific example from -1-, I was getting the following errors as well the moment sGroup.setInput() is used instead of mBlur.setInput()

```
E/RenderScript(12023): Blur executed without input, skipping
```

This appears to be bug(s) in renderscript

-3-
Specifically, in your case, where you want to do ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix with ScriptIntrinsicBlur in a sequence, there is another issue (not necessarily a bug). While Blur intrinsic has a setInput function, colorMatrix does have a setInput function. So you cannot use -1- as a workaround as well.

-4-
I think the right fixes in renderscript would to be to deprecate
intrinsic.setInput universally just as it was done for ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix and get ScriptGroup.setInput working while using intrinsics in a script group.

-5-
I did not see any issues using scriptgroup, when I have my own kernels. In other words, scriptGroup.setInput() and scriptGroup.setOutput() work perfectly fine

Comment: I tried, that doesn't make a difference. I mean putting two rs intrinsics into a Script Group, then there is no output displayed on image view. I uploaded my test project here: https://github.com/laoyang/rstest  if you want to take a look. Thank you!

Comment: refined my analysis. see above.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, I switched the order, let the blur to be the first one, and set its input. The Script group is working now. So I guess render script is still not mature...

Comment: ScriptGroup will be getting an overhaul at some point--it's just less important than a lot of other things right now. I'll see if I can add a fix for this intrinsic situation in the interim, though.

Comment: @TimMurray Did the bug get fixed?